# jquery drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I found the  following example on this [website](http://web-design-dubai-uae.blogspot.com/2009/09/jquery-drag-and-drop.html).

What I want is:

1. I want to be able to drag items back from the Thrash
2. How can I get the total number of pictures in an album and trash to store in MySQL using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is create an AJAX call. Using the [$.ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to send data from the browser when the user performs a drag and drop to the server. With the php code, you'll need to setup handlers to accept the data coming from the javascript.